# using postgres date functions in sequelize where condition

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I need to apply a where condition in sequelize by using postgres date function.Following is the query

```
    where created_at between date_trunc('month', current_date) and date_trunc('month',
current_date)+'1month'
```

I tried this

```
    where:{user_id:user_id,created_at:{ [Op.between]: [[db.sequelize.literal('date_trunc(month, current_date)'),'test'],
[db.sequelize.literal('date_trunc(month, current_date)+1month'),'curr']]}}
```

How this can be achieved by using sequelize ORM.Thanks in advance

Comment: worked with where:db.sequelize.literal(' created_at between date_trunc(\'month\', current_date) and date_trunc(\'month\',current_date)+\'1month\'')});